# Coloring maps by feature orientation

Tags: tectonics, mapping

I live in the SF Bay Area where many, but not all, geological features are oriented parallel to the San Andreas Fault. I was wondering if there’s a type of map where ridges are colored by compass orientation, so perhaps N-S features are blue and E-W features are yellow, with lots of gradations in between. Seems like it would help identify features produced by the same forces (at least as a first guess). Does this type of map exist? If so, what’s it called? If not, would it actually be useful?

Comment: I could write a partial answer based on using Python to color a topographical map [downloaded in this way](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/13852/21170) (see also [this incredible answer!](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/16536/6031))  if that would be of interest. It won't address all parts of your question but at least then you could have a height map and a gradient map and a few ways to choose how to assign a color to a particular gradient direction and strength. Would that be of interest?